# Flutter Web - iFrame - refused to connect

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to handle the payment gateway in Android, iOS & Web apps. We have used `WebViewWidget` to handle the mobile and it's working as expected. However, we are trying to replicate the same in the web app using `iFrame` but facing the following issue.

- Getting error **xyz.com refused to connect**
- Few of the websites it's loading but after one or two redirections get the same above error, refused to connect.
- It is not detecting the URL change, it is always printing the initial URL.

Thanks in advance.

```
void setupIFrame(String? src, double width, double height) {
    final key = widget.key ?? ValueKey('');
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('iframe-$src', (int viewId) {
      final element = html.IFrameElement();
      element
        ..src = src
        ..style.border = 'none'
        ..height = height.toInt().toString()
        ..width = width.toInt().toString();

      element.onLoad.listen((event) {
        // URL has changed
        Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          final currentUrl = element.src;
          debugPrint('URL changed to: $currentUrl');
        });
      });

      return element;
    });
```

Adding the iFrame to widget,

```
AbsorbPointer(
   child: RepaintBoundary(
      child: HtmlElementView(
         key: widget.key,
         viewType: 'iframe-$url',
       ),
    ),
)
```